# Modify value of variable inside an Object (java)

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am quite new to java and I'm trying to create student record system.
At the moment I'm storing my "registered student" in an `ArrayList` of `Object`s.

I would like to be able to modify the value of for e.g. the first name of a specific student.  The ID of the student is also his position in the `ArrayList`.

Here is how I tried to do it but it doesnt seem to work:

```
StudentStoring.StudentList.get(id)
    .setTitle(comboTitle.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

This is the bit of code that is suppose to take the new value of the title in the modifying page and replace the old one but I get an `IndexOutOfBound` error.

Thanks.

Comment: IndexOutOfBound means that your `id` is beyond the length of the array. Keep in mind that the first index is 0 (not 1).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says,

```
/**
 * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
 *
 * @param  index index of the element to return
 * @return the element at the specified position in this list
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    return elementData(index);
}
```

which means if the list has 5 elements (index 0 to 4). If your are trying to get 10th element (index 9) then it will throws IndexOutOfBoundsException. So in your code,

`StudentStoring.StudentList.get(id).setTitle(comboTitle.getSelectedItem().toString());`

id will have a value greater than the size of the array list. Try to debug in IDE or just print the value of id you can easily find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to get Index value of list which you want to update then use [public E set(int index,
             E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) method to replace value

```
Student s=new Student();
 s.setId(id); 
 s.setTitle(comboTitle.getSelectedItem().toString());


StudentStoring.StudentList.set(index,comboTitle.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Comment: That is not necessarily better, as it does not update an existing Student, but replaces it with a new one. Anyone else who has a reference to the object won't see the updates.